# How to fail an build when the file can not be found in an JAVA target using ANT

Tags: java, ant

When I run my ant script, the output on the console is like this:

```
run:

 [java] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '../ui/css/kknormalize.css' does not exist
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1074)
 [java]     at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1038)
 [java]     at xmlReader.ProcessHBS.copyFiles(ProcessHBS.java:177)
 [java]     at xmlReader.ProcessHBS.scriptSelection(ProcessHBS.java:115)
 [java]     at xmlReader.DemoIt.main(DemoIt.java:53)
```

There is an exception in java IO(the file can not be found). However in the final step of the console, it printed:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

I set the fork to 'true' and failonerror to 'true' when running the ANT script. Is there a way to let the build fail when there is such an exception? Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Affirmed.Virtualization BuildTool. See if there is a way to configure the build tool to return a non-zero return code when a FileNotFoundException happens. Otherwise, you may have to log the output of the build tool into an Ant property and later use a combination of the `<fail>` and `<contains>` tasks.